# Ember.js server side pagination

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008838/ember-pagination-full-example) perfectly working pagination solution.

It has a feature: it asks the server the whole set of data. I would like only a portion of it to be requested.

What do i need to do in ember-data to configure my requests so that they include some more parameters with the page info?

thank you

UPDATE:
done in this way:

```
App.Books = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set 'content', App.Book.find({page_number: controller.get('currentPage')})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send query to `find` method of the `DS.Model`. So if you have endpoint that follows OData protocol you would do this:

```
App.Post.find({ '$top': 10, '$skip': 0 });
```

and it would return you only first 10 posts.

Comment: of course, but how do i give as actual parameters (or how do i calculate) the 'top' and 'skip' parameters into my route?