# Pagination in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, pagination

I have an Ember Data module which loads items in the database to render it in View as a table. Is there a way to convert this table to pagination i.e. view 15 items in each page and control buttons to jump between pages?

Comment: This might helps ,



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008838/ember-pagination-full-example

Comment: Looks like a good guide! Will give it a shot :) Thanks!