# How to get count of model records without loading them all

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem. I have a news model in my background application and my Emberjs app. And there are a lot of news posts can be stored, so I have to divide loading them to some pages or whatever. The problem is - I need to always get a full count of not readed news posts. What is the best way to implement such behaviour in my Ember application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember pagination full example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008838/ember-pagination-full-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ember Data, I would take a look at [Handling Metadata](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/).

The default JSON deserializer looks for a property named `meta` which could contain something like `"totalUnreadPosts": 10`

You could get to the metadata with `var metaData = store.metaDataFor('newsPost');` which would allow you to get a count without having to load every post.

Comment: Just before you wrote it I found out it my self :) But anyway thanks.